# PHPUnit annotation throwing ReflectionException: Class does not exist

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to capture the exception using phpUnit annotations:

```
/**
 * @expectedException Drupal\apple_news\Api\Exception\ApiException.
*/
public function testDecodeResponse() {
  $this->client->decodeResponse('');
}
```

Seems ok, and in fact if I use setExpectedException works fine, but I get:

```
ReflectionException: Class Drupal\apple_news\Api\Exception\ApiException. does not exist
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove a dot.

```
/**
 * @expectedException Drupal\apple_news\Api\Exception\ApiException // <- here
*/
```

Comment: ah, seriously, I feel really stupid now :-D. Thank you mate